# Mongooose: How to get a id from a find array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a group-based document application, an error is happening in the sharing part. The application is composed of the following parts: Groups, viewers, users and documents.

A group can have many viewers and users, a user can have many documents. I'm working on the part where viewers can see all documents of users associated with the group the viewer is associated with

**My controller**

```
router.get("link", async (req, res) => {
        const group = await Group.find({ viewer: req.session.userId }).select("id")
        console.log(group); // This console.log returns the id in a array: [ { _id: new ObjectId("6323a88670c0dd9aaa5017d2") } ]
        console.log(group.id); // This console.log returns undefined

        const user = await User.find({ group: group.id });
        console.log(user); // Nothing because the group.id is undefined

        const documents = await Document.find({
          user: user.id,
        });

        return res.render("page", {
          documents,
        });
```

**Group schema**

```
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  viewer: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  }],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  }
```

I'm not able to retrieve the id from Group.find; what could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want to have one value. So you can use `findOne`. Due to using `findOne`, you can reach `group._id`

```
const group = await Group.findOne({ viewer: req.session.userId }).select("id")
console.log(group); // { _id: new ObjectId("6323a88670c0dd9aaa5017d2") }
```

If you try to take the value from your array, you should take the 0. element of the array. Because it is an array and has elements. You are trying to reach the element's id value.

But which element's id? You need to declare it. Therefore, need to use `group[0]._id`. But if you want to reach just one element, using `findOne()` is a better choice.

```
const group = await Group.find({ viewer: req.session.userId }).select("id")
console.log(group[0]); // { _id: new ObjectId("6323a88670c0dd9aaa5017d2") }
```

I hope, it is clear and helps you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @onur-doğan, the viewer can be in multiple groups and I'm trying to get the docs from all of them, I'll try something related to map or for each

Comment: Hmm. I understood. So, you are right. After find method, you will already reached all Groups which has viewer's id. Then need to use map or for of to get them with a loop. If you can't reach the result you wish, you may tell me too. I can help you if you need. Good luck friend.